# Node js - best approach to create many child processes

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I have a main nodejs application that loops over a list of websites and creates a child process for each website to gather information from that site (scraping).

my problem is that I may have many websites (say 100, 200 or more) what is the best approach for such problem?

is there a better system design for this?

or can I run that much of node js apps on the same device if I skipped using the main app.

please advise.

Comment: The best approach is *not* to create a separate child process for each website. Nodejs can handle concurrent web scraping in a single process just fine.